# git push error: Server aborted the SSL handshake

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I've been able to push-to-deploy with my appengine project for a while now. Latest push was 3 days ago. No issues.

Today, I'm receiving the error:

> fatal: unable to access '[repo_url]': Server aborted the SSL handshake

Any ideas?

Comment: I had an issue like this pop up when trying to `git push` from `cron`. Just had to set `$HOME` manually to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use with `http.sslVerify=false` in the User Settings.

If you are using eclipse Find

```
Window-->Preferences-->Git-->Configuration-->User Settings
-->http.sslVerify(Key)=false(value).
```

If it is worked i.e. your  Ssl Certificate is  Expired.

Answer (score 1):

I was just getting the exact same error. Tried pushing half a dozen times over a five minute period and the last time it just magically worked. I hadn't changed a thing. Perhaps it's an issue on the github servers..?

Comment: There is a DDoS attack on GitHub. I assume they are working on it to fix it and might already succeed the last time you tried: https://status.github.com/messages

Answer (score 1):

try this `git push --set-upstream origin your_branch`